# How can I use command line arguments to control a batch program that prints multi-colour text?

Tags: function, colors, batch-file, command

I have a batch script that can display two or more colors of text on the same line in the command prompt. (below)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
set "DEL=%%a"
)
echo say the name of the colors, don't read

call :ColorText 0a "blue"
call :ColorText 0C "green"
call :ColorText 0b "red"
echo(
call :ColorText 19 "yellow"
call :ColorText 2F "black"
call :ColorText 4e "white"
pause
goto :eof

:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

however that text must be entered in the script before-hand by editing the batch file with notepad. i'd like to be able to just open the command prompt and type something like:

```
cecho /blue hello world!
```

or

```
cecho blue "hello world!"
```

or something simple where i can supply the color (preferably as a string not a color code) and text (with or without quotations).

---

I don't know if this is of any use to you but it is possible to save this part of the script:

```
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

(from ":ColorText" to the end of the script)
and save it as "ColorText.bat" in "C:\windows\system32". Then in the other half of the script, everywhere you see:

```
call :ColorText
```

Change it to:

```
call ColorText
```

(Omit the colons)
And save that script as colors.bat in "C:\windows\system32". Then open the command prompt and type "colors". This is how i want it to function; no additional commands, setup scripts, file paths; just a simple one or two word function with all that messy code going on in the background (out of sight). However the above idea still won't let me specify my own text or color from the command prompt.... any ideas?

Comment: Don't put own files in system locations. You can change the `PATH` environment variable to add a location residing in your profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Take 3

Create the folder `C:\Utilities`.  Add this folder to your Path environment variable so Windows looks there for additional scripts and commands.

1. Open Control Panel, System, Advanced System Settings (or "Advanced" in Windows XP), Environment Variables.
2. In the "System variables" list, select the "Path" variable.
   **Do not mess these next steps up!**
3. Press Edit.
4. Place the cursor at the end of the line and make sure no text is selected.
5. Add the text `;C:\Utilities`, including the semi-colon.  Do not remove any other text.
6. Press OK.
   **Breathe easy again.**
7. Press OK as many times as necessary to close all windows.

Take the script following the `:ColorText` label and save it to `C:\Utilities\cecho.bat`.  Put an `@` in front of `echo off` to prevent `echo off` from appearing during the script.

**CEcho.bat**

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a In ('"Prompt #$H#$E# & Echo On & For %%b In (1) Do Rem"') Do (
Set "DEL=%%a"
)
<Nul Set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
FindStr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" Nul
Del "%~2" > Nul 2>&1
EndLocal
```

Now you can use this command from any command line or script.  Usage:

```
CEcho color "text"
```

**Edit:** In response to your comment:

You can use words for colours by inserting the following lines and replacing the `FindStr` line:

```
Set Color=%1
If %1==blue Set Color=9
If %1==red Set Color=C
etc...
FindStr /v /a:%Color% /R "^$" "%~2" Nul
```

Now you can type:

```
CEcho red "apple"
CEcho blue "water"
CEcho A "grass"
CEcho 6 "dirt"
CEcho 26 "tree"
```

Note that the color word is case sensitive.

Comment: copied your above code, saved it as C:\windows\system32\cecho.bat opened the command line and typed "cecho fc hello" and got nothing at all. i also tried several different colors (both string format and hex digit format) and got nothing.

Comment: Hand: Sorry, I didn't read that far in the question when I posted that comment ... I moved it to the question now. Apologies.

Comment: I just tried your script and it appears that isn't working.  In fact, looking at it now, I can't even work out what `:ColorText` is meant to do.  What is it meant to do?  **Edit:** Just working it out.  It doesn't work, but I see the idea behind it.  One minute...

Comment: I condensed the script, but you're right, it seems to not colour text.  I'm starting to think `FindStr /A` simple doesn't work.

Comment: If you would spend your time to copy the sample, you could see that it works. It needs to search in TWO files, and it can only color the filename not the content. As it always append a colon to the filename, I remove it with a backspace in the content.

Comment: i tried your idea above and it doesnt work... i know it works with any text you enter in the script but i want it to color the text you enter in the command line..

Comment: @jeb: Wow!  I thought most of the script was just to call the colour routine.  I've updated the script and this one works for me.

Comment: ok that works now thanks alot! also, if you have a second, could you please tell me where i would define the names of the colors as their hexidecimal values? (for example: set red = 4)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the batch parameters %1, %2, ...,  %n, as parameter for the color and for the content

`cecho 0a "hello world!"`

```
@echo off
call :ColorText %1 "%~2"
...
```

If you want to use the color names you have to convert them to the corresponding number.

`cecho blue "hello"`

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="red" set color=0c
if "%1"=="blue" set color=0b
if ...
call :ColorText %color% "%~2"
```

Comment: so just to make sure i got it right, what would the final script be for cecho and what is the syntax

Comment: It depedens on your preferences, if you want to use color names take the second snippet and add all color names

Comment: say if i wanted to just type "cecho red "hello"", what would the final script be? i can't get it to work...

Comment: It is simpler and faster to previously define a series of variables with the color codes: `set blue=1` `set green=2` `. . .` `set brightwhite=0F` and use they this way: `call cecho %yellow% "A message in yellow"`. These values also works in COLOR command: `color %blue%%white%.

Answer (score 0):

A *fast* alternative to color **efficiently** with cmd batch since *Windows XP* by using PowerShell as a subprocess linked to the console output through a named pipe. It can be done with FindStr too, but PowerShell offers more options and seems quicker.

The main interest in keeping PowerShell as a subprocess, using a pipe to communicate, is that the display is **far more faster** than launching PowerShell or FindStr for each line to display.

Other good points :

- No need for temporary files
- Echoing though a pipe permits the display of the full ASCII table without bothering escapes.
- Works fine with fd redirection. To color only stderr as example, or to redirect to a file / other process.

Here is a sample code for doing that :

```
::
:: Launch a PowerShell child process in the background linked to the console and 
:: earing through named pipe PowerShellCon_%PID%
::
:: Parameters :
::   [ PID ] : Console Process ID used as an identifier for the named pipe, launcher PID by default.
::   [ timeout ] : Subprocess max life in seconds, 300 by default. If -1, the subprocess
::                  will not terminate while the process %PID% is still alive.
:: Return :
::   0 if the child PowerShell has been successfully launched and the named pipe is available.
::   1 if it fails.
::   2 if we can't get a PID.
::   3 if PowerShell is not present or doesn't work.
::
:LaunchPowerShellSubProcess
  SET LOCALV_PID=
  SET LOCALV_TIMEOUT=300
  IF NOT "%~1" == "" SET LOCALV_PID=%~1
  IF NOT "%~2" == "" SET LOCALV_TIMEOUT=%~2
  powershell -command "$_" 2>&1 >NUL
  IF NOT "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" EXIT /B 3
  IF "!LOCALV_PID!" == "" (
    FOR /F %%P IN ('powershell -command "$parentId=(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$PID).ParentProcessId; write-host (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$parentId).ParentProcessId;"') DO (
      SET LOCALV_PID=%%P
    )
  )
  IF "!LOCALV_PID!" == "" EXIT /B 2
  START /B powershell -command "$cmdPID=$PID; Start-Job -ArgumentList $cmdPID -ScriptBlock { $ProcessActive = $true; $timeout=!LOCALV_TIMEOUT!; while((!LOCALV_TIMEOUT! -eq -1 -or $timeout -gt 0) -and $ProcessActive) { Start-Sleep -s 1; $timeout-=1; $ProcessActive = Get-Process -id !LOCALV_PID! -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; } if ($timeout -eq 0 -or ^! $ProcessActive) { Stop-Process -Id $args; } } | Out-Null ; $npipeServer = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream('PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!', [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::In); Try { $npipeServer.WaitForConnection(); $pipeReader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($npipeServer); while(($msg = $pipeReader.ReadLine()) -notmatch 'QUIT') { $disp='write-host '+$msg+';'; invoke-expression($disp); $npipeServer.Disconnect(); $npipeServer.WaitForConnection(); }; } Finally { $npipeServer.Dispose(); }" 2>NUL
  SET /A LOCALV_TRY=20 >NUL
  :LaunchPowerShellSubProcess_WaitForPipe
  powershell -nop -c "& {sleep -m 50}"
  SET /A LOCALV_TRY=!LOCALV_TRY! - 1 >NUL
  IF NOT "!LOCALV_TRY!" == "0" cmd /C "ECHO -NoNewLine|MORE 1>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!" 2>NUL || GOTO:LaunchPowerShellSubProcess_WaitForPipe
  IF "!LOCALV_TRY!" == "0" EXIT /B 1
  EXIT /B 0
```

This "code" is written with delayed expansion **ON** but can be rewrite to work without it. There is many security points to consider, do not use it directly *in the wild*.

How to use it :

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  ECHO Extension inapplicable
  EXIT /B 1
)
::
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  ECHO Expansion inapplicable
  EXIT /B 1
)
CALL:LaunchPowerShellSubProcess
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 EXIT /B 1
CALL:Color Cyan "I write this in Cyan"
CALL:Blue "I write this in Blue"
CALL:Green "And this in green"
CALL:Red -nonewline "And mix Red"
CALL:Yellow "with Yellow"
CALL:Green "And not need to trouble with ()<>&|;,%""^ and so on..."
EXIT /B 0
:Color
ECHO -foregroundcolor %*>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!
ECHO[|SET /P=>NUL
GOTO:EOF
:Blue
ECHO -foregroundcolor Blue %*>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!
ECHO[|SET /P=>NUL
GOTO:EOF
:Green
ECHO -foregroundcolor Green %*>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!
ECHO[|SET /P=>NUL
GOTO:EOF
:Red
ECHO -foregroundcolor Red %*>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!
ECHO[|SET /P=>NUL
GOTO:EOF
:Yellow
ECHO -foregroundcolor Yellow %*>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!
ECHO[|SET /P=>NUL
GOTO:EOF
::
:: Launch a PowerShell child process in the background linked to the console and 
:: earing through named pipe PowerShellCon_%PID%
::
:: Parameters :
::   [ PID ] : Console Process ID used as an identifier for the named pipe, launcher PID by default.
::   [ timeout ] : Subprocess max life in seconds, 300 by default. If -1, the subprocess
::                  will not terminate while the process %PID% is still alive.
:: Return :
::   0 if the child PowerShell has been successfully launched and the named pipe is available.
::   1 if it fails.
::   2 if we can't get a PID.
::   3 if PowerShell is not present or doesn't work.
::
:LaunchPowerShellSubProcess
  SET LOCALV_PID=
  SET LOCALV_TIMEOUT=300
  IF NOT "%~1" == "" SET LOCALV_PID=%~1
  IF NOT "%~2" == "" SET LOCALV_TIMEOUT=%~2
  powershell -command "$_" 2>&1 >NUL
  IF NOT "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" EXIT /B 3
  IF "!LOCALV_PID!" == "" (
    FOR /F %%P IN ('powershell -command "$parentId=(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$PID).ParentProcessId; write-host (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$parentId).ParentProcessId;"') DO (
      SET LOCALV_PID=%%P
    )
  )
  IF "!LOCALV_PID!" == "" EXIT /B 2
  START /B powershell -command "$cmdPID=$PID; Start-Job -ArgumentList $cmdPID -ScriptBlock { $ProcessActive = $true; $timeout=!LOCALV_TIMEOUT!; while((!LOCALV_TIMEOUT! -eq -1 -or $timeout -gt 0) -and $ProcessActive) { Start-Sleep -s 1; $timeout-=1; $ProcessActive = Get-Process -id !LOCALV_PID! -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; } if ($timeout -eq 0 -or ^! $ProcessActive) { Stop-Process -Id $args; } } | Out-Null ; $npipeServer = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream('PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!', [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::In); Try { $npipeServer.WaitForConnection(); $pipeReader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($npipeServer); while(($msg = $pipeReader.ReadLine()) -notmatch 'QUIT') { $disp='write-host '+$msg+';'; invoke-expression($disp); $npipeServer.Disconnect(); $npipeServer.WaitForConnection(); }; } Finally { $npipeServer.Dispose(); }" 2>NUL
  SET /A LOCALV_TRY=20 >NUL
  :LaunchPowerShellSubProcess_WaitForPipe
  powershell -nop -c "& {sleep -m 50}"
  SET /A LOCALV_TRY=!LOCALV_TRY! - 1 >NUL
  IF NOT "!LOCALV_TRY!" == "0" cmd /C "ECHO -NoNewLine|MORE 1>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!" 2>NUL || GOTO:LaunchPowerShellSubProcess_WaitForPipe
  IF "!LOCALV_TRY!" == "0" EXIT /B 1
  EXIT /B 0
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66604485/3641635) to my original answer on the same topic.